# How to convert string that uses "\r\n" as line breaks to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pgp

I have a string `bytearray(b'onefish,twofish,greenfish,bluefish\r\n1,2,3,4')` I get this string from an encrypted csv file using the `pgpy` library.

I need my dataframe to look like this.

```
      onefish twofish greenfish bluefish
0     1       2       3         4
```

So far I use multiple `for` loops that make lists that I then put into a dictionary.

How can approach this using: 
`df = pd.Dataframe(bytearray(b'onefish,twofish,greenfish,bluefish\r\n1,2,3,4')` to get the output I want above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- from given data. Split data by '\r\n'.
- assuming First row is always header pass that as columns and rest of the rows as data.

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>b = b'onefish,twofish,greenfish,bluefish\r\n1,2,3,4\r\n5,6,7,8' 
>>>data = list(map(lambda x: x.split(','),b.decode('utf-8').split("\r\n")))
>>>pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

    onefish     twofish     greenfish   bluefish
0      1          2            3           4
1      5          6            7           8
```

Comment: Solid solution but you might want to break up the data line into steps so its clearer to the OP what each is doing

Comment: @sedavidw Done. Removed unnecessary map. Its more clear now. Also added small description.

Comment: hey how do you get the `b` in front of a string?

Comment: You can just type. `b` represents binary string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use io.BytesIO as far as I'm aware:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(bytearray(b'onefish,twofish,greenfish,bluefish\r\n1,2,3,4\r\n5,6,7,8\r\n9,10,11,12')))

print(df)

   onefish  twofish  greenfish  bluefish
0        1        2          3         4
1        5        6          7         8
2        9       10         11        12
```

Comment: This kinda works but i only get one column with all the info, its not splitting into 4 columns.

Comment: The first part is columns so you need to add that to df seperatly.