# Encoding issue using panda.read_csv resulting in misread rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Whilst importing a .tsv file using `panda.read_csv(file_name.tsv, sep = "\t")` I noticed that a few entries were a lot longer than others. Upon further investigation, I noticed long entries that failed to be represented as new rows because of the "\r\n" not being recognized as a new row.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have attached samples, and after trying to replace the string with no success, was hoping to find a solution.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, images are not.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57894697/how-to-convert-string-that-uses-r-n-as-line-breaks-to-pandas-dataframe)